# TypeORM generates an empty migration

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, typeorm

Whenever I run `typeorm migration:generate -n NAME`, all I get is an error stating I that no changes to the database were made. Whenever I run `typeorm migration:create -n NAME`, I get an empty migration file. All of my entities are in the folder specified in the `ormconfig.json` file, and are in the .ts format. When running a migration:generate command, I get an error that is related to the syntax in my entities (specifically where I have my imports on top of the file).

This is my `ormconfig.json`:

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "admin",
  "database": "classmarker",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "src/entity/*.ts"
  ],
  "subscribers": [
    "src/subscriber/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/migration/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

My package.json contains the following packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tsed/common": "^5.21.0",
    "@tsed/core": "^5.21.0",
    "@tsed/di": "^5.21.0",
    "@types/mssql": "^4.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.12",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  }
```

And my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

The error I get when running `typeorm migration:generate -n Name`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Function.PlatformTools.load (%AppData%\nvm\v8.11.2\node_modules\typeorm\platform\PlatformTools.js:107:28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Unexpected token import` tends to show up when you try to generate or run a migration that is in the .ts format (I presume that it shows up due to you trying to `import` something at the top of your `.ts` file). Since TypeORM works properly with .js instead of .ts (don't ask why), try running `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n NAME` to generate a migration and `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run` to push it to the database instead.

Essentially, it's easier to add something like this into your `package.json`:

```
    "add-migration": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n",
    "update-database": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run"
```

Then you can simply run them using `npm run add-migration -n NAME` and `npm run update-database`.

> **typeorm migration:create** and **typeorm migration:generate** will create ts files. The **migration:run** and **migration:revert** commands only work on .js files. Thus the typescript files need to be compiled before running the commands. Alternatively you can use ts-node in conjunction with typeorm to run .ts migration files.

- Source: [Link](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#running-and-reverting-migrations)